# Internal Failures when using Spring-Integration-Kinesis Message Driven Adapter

Tags: spring, spring-integration, amazon-kinesis, spring-integration-aws

I have set up this KinesisMessageDrivenChannelAdapter:

```
@Bean
public KinesisMessageDrivenChannelAdapter kinesisInboundChannel(AmazonKinesis amazonKinesis, MetadataStore store) {
    KinesisMessageDrivenChannelAdapter adapter =
        new KinesisMessageDrivenChannelAdapter(amazonKinesis, config.getStreamName());
    adapter.setCheckpointMode(CheckpointMode.batch);
    adapter.setListenerMode(ListenerMode.batch);
    adapter.setStartTimeout(10000);
    // Set idle to milliseconds.  Max value is 596 before getting an overflow exception.
    adapter.setIdleBetweenPolls(config.getPollHours() * 3_600_000);

    adapter.setShouldTrack(true);
    adapter.setDescribeStreamRetries(5);
    adapter.setConcurrency(50);
    adapter.setCheckpointStore(store);
    adapter.setStreamInitialSequence(KinesisShardOffset.trimHorizon());
    adapter.setOutputChannelName("logMessage.input");
    adapter.setErrorChannel(errorChannel());
    return adapter;
}
```

Most of the time, it works fine.  But from time to time, I get this kind of message:

```
Exception in thread "kinesisInboundChannel-kinesis-consumer-1" com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.model.AmazonKinesisException: null (Service: AmazonKinesis; Status Code: 500; Error Code: InternalFailure; Request ID: c2f66be9-23f4-b211-9165-ed92383ee673)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1639)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1304)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1056)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:743)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:717)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:699)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:667)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:649)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:513)
    at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.AmazonKinesisClient.doInvoke(AmazonKinesisClient.java:2276)
    at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.AmazonKinesisClient.invoke(AmazonKinesisClient.java:2252)
    at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.AmazonKinesisClient.executeGetRecords(AmazonKinesisClient.java:1062)
    at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.AmazonKinesisClient.getRecords(AmazonKinesisClient.java:1038)
    at org.springframework.integration.aws.inbound.kinesis.KinesisMessageDrivenChannelAdapter$ShardConsumer.getRecords(KinesisMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.java:853)
    at org.springframework.integration.aws.inbound.kinesis.KinesisMessageDrivenChannelAdapter$ShardConsumer.access$3500(KinesisMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.java:688)
    at org.springframework.integration.aws.inbound.kinesis.KinesisMessageDrivenChannelAdapter$ShardConsumer$2.run(KinesisMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.java:816)
    at org.springframework.integration.aws.inbound.kinesis.KinesisMessageDrivenChannelAdapter$ConsumerInvoker.run(KinesisMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.java:1003)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
```

After that, the adapter stops working entirely without hanging the app.  I specified what error channel to use, and I'd be happy to just restart the application to bring the adapter back online if I need to.  But that appears to not be an option.

How do I build error handling into this?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a problem has been fixed here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-aws/issues/84

You need to consider to use the latest version (2.0.0.M2), or even better `2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT`.